# Django easymode i18n suddenly failing?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-database

I started getting:

```
OperationalError at /admin/contact_us/contact_details/
(1054, "Unknown column 'contact_us_contact_details.address_title' in 'field list'")
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://216.119.153.206/admin/contact_us/contact_details/
Django Version: 1.4 pre-alpha SVN-16280
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
(1054, "Unknown column 'contact_us_contact_details.address_title' in 'field list'")
Exception Location: /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py in defaulterrorhandler, line 36
```

My model looks like (Singleton):

```
@I18n('address_title','contact_info','contact_form_header','accepted_message','error_message')
class Contact_details(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Contact Details'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contact Details'
    address_title = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    title_font = models.ForeignKey(Font,blank=True,null=True)
    contact_form_header = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    contact_form_header_use_title_font = models.NullBooleanField(default=True,blank=True,null=True)
    google_map_link = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    contact_info = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    accepted_message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    error_message = models.TextField(blank=True)


    def save(self):
        self.id = 1
        super(Contact_details,self).save()

    def delete(self):
        pass

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Contact Us Details'
```

I'm using South for DB migrations to production. When I use MySQL Workbench to inspect the contact_us_contact_details table I see that both **address_title_en and address_title_fr** are present (only supported languages)

Anyone have ideas where this error is coming from? I was in the process of installing Haystack and Whoosh when I started encountering this issue.

**EDIT**:
For testing purposes I added the address_title column to the MySQL DB and it worked (well it stopped failing on that column and started failing on the next column)

Comment: I need to do a bit more investigation but it seems that as soon as I create a search_indexes.py file for an application something goes wrong within easymodes i18n. Any better explanations would be appreciated as I'm now facing an issue of combining haystack and easymode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you might want to check out http://packages.python.org/django-easymode/i18n/index.html#use-lazy-foreign-keys and http://packages.python.org/django-easymode/i18n/index.html#haystack If you follow these instructions everything should work fine.

The bottom line is:

Register your models for haystack inside the models.py module and not in the search_indexes module.